# How to resolve 'Cannot find symbol JsonMessageConverter"?

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring boot version 2.0.0 but I am getting the following error

> import
>   org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter;
>                                                    ^ symbol:   class JsonMessageConverter location: package
>   org.springframework.amqp.support.converter 1 error

Is there any equivalent of JsonMessageConverter I can use without affecting my coding flow and process?

Answer (score 0):

Check it out the JSON message converter. 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest